# How to remove "L" which comes after each list value in Django

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I did a query to get all the field values from a model.I stored the result in a queryset.

```
queryset=Books.objects.filter(book_type="comic")
```

Now when i filter this queryset :

```
query=queryset.filter(~Q(auther_id=1))
autherList=[]
for q in query:
    autherList.append(q.auther_id)
print autherList
```

It print the list as:

```
[3L, 4L, 9L, 13L, 53L, 53L, 102L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L]
```

My question is : What does this L signify and how to remove it to get a simple list of ids.

I looked over this but could not find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `L` denotes that the items are of `long` type.

The underlying database library (mysql may be?) is creating the `long` types while fetching them from the db. So they are `long` instead of plain old `int`.

You can convert them to integers using the `int` function.

```
>>> lng_number = 23L

>>> int_num = int(lng_number)

>>> int_num
23
```

If all the values are of the `long` type, you can use `map` like this:

```
>>> long_list = [1L, 3L, 10L]

>>> int_list = map(int, long_list)

>>> int_list
[1, 3, 10]

>>>
```

Comment: Could be written as list comprehension, which some regard more readable than map(): `int_list = [int(item) for item in long_list]`.

Answer (score 3):

That's not an literal `L`, it represents data type `long`. It's just a command line representation, you shouldn't worry about it because it will only hold more digits for your model `id` field.

Comment: ids are stored as int ,then how does it become  of "long" data type.

Comment: Its the auther id which is auto generated which shows type int in my DB.

Comment: I have answered it in my question. It depends on the underlying database library.

Comment: It's should be long integer to be exact, because id might grow out of the limit of what `int` can hold. It's just a way that command line representation, it won't affect how you use the id.

Comment: Thank you so much @ShangWang

Answer (score 2):

I have tried this and it works

```
>>> a = [3L, 4L, 9L, 13L, 53L, 53L, 102L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L] 
>>> b = map(int,a)
>>> b
[3, 4, 9, 13, 53, 53, 102, 111, 111, 111, 111]
```

But you don't have to worry about it because Python treat it as numbers

```
>>> a = [3L, 4L, 9L, 13L, 53L, 53L, 102L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L] 
>>> b = [c*2 for c in a]
>>> b
[6L, 8L, 18L, 26L, 106L, 106L, 204L, 222L, 222L, 222L, 222L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this one 

[3L, 4L, 9L, 13L, 53L, 53L, 102L, 111L, 111L, 111L, 111L] 

use this ::
remove_extra = [int(item_list) for item_list in remove_extra]


****** if you want to remove duplicate value from list then use **set()**

like this::


**list(set(remove_extra))**
```

Comment: why not simply use `map`?

Comment: @AbuAshrafMasnun.... You don't need map inside your list comprehension. Map creates another list so you end up with a list of list.

Comment: I didn't mean using map inside the list comprehension. You can use it instead of the list comprehension.